# Why can't I see autofill commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

When I type in something like `/locatebiome desert`, nothing comes up. I can see everything else but the autofill commands for some reason. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to press tab for it to autofill the other options. `/locatebiome desert` is also the maximum amount of arguments that command can have, so it wouldn't give you any autofill options regardless.